# Blazor Custom Validator cannot pass variable text

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a custom razor component that creates a custom InputText box and in the model when I set the custom validator I want to send into the validator a custom ErrorMessage based on language.

When I add the following code I get an error An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'member' Compiler Error CS0120.

Is it possible to use a property to send into the class?

**RazorPage.cs**

```
// order_by_RequiredErrorText property is set on initialized and set based on the language
    [Parameter] public string access_level_RequiredErrorText { get; set; }
    
    // This works but I dont want only english
    [CustomValidatorIsRequired(IsRequiredErrorText = "This is an error message")] 
    [Parameter] public string order_by_Text { get; set; } 
    
    // This throws an error
    [CustomValidatorIsRequired(IsRequiredErrorText = order_by_RequiredErrorText)] 
    [Parameter] public string order_by_Text { get; set; }
```

**CustomValidator.cs**

```
public class CustomValidatorIsRequired : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public string IsRequiredErrorText { get; set; }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                string sValue = value.ToString();
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sValue))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return new ValidationResult($"{IsRequiredErrorText}", new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
            }
            else
                return null;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to move to a custom validator.  You can find several on the internet including one I've written. Search "blazor custom validation".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, where do I find your custom validator?